# Indeterminate progress bar within data bound listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, progress-bar

I have a listview that is bound to an object and in the listview I want each record to have its own progress bar (indeterminate) that I can start so the user knows something is happening with that record.  This progress bar has no % because I am indexing files and I have no starting count to create a percentage from.  So I tried adding a "progress bar" to my object and binding it but all that displays is "System.windows...." instead of the actual progress bar.  Does anyone know how to bind that progress bar correctly so I can start/stop it for each record?

Here is some snippets on how my data is bound

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DbaseCollection, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"

<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" 
                HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource searchResultsColumnHeader}"
                customcontrols:GridViewSort.PropertyName="Name" Width="Auto">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a `CellTemplate` (do *not* use `DisplayMemberBinding` at the same time)

```
<GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ProgressBar .../>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

What properties on the `ProgressBar` you bind is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the correct direction...I created a DataTemplate in my resource file and bind the IsIndeterminate value to a property on my object...I add/remove the column when the action is being performed on the records so the progress bar is only seen when the user needs to see it, but it works great!

Comment: <DataTemplate x:Key="ProgressBarTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="{Binding StartProgressBar}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                     Height="10" MinWidth="60"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>